# Session Persistence in Nginx for load balancing

Tags: session, cookies, nginx, load-balancing

In Nginx, there are three methods regarding session persistence: sticky cookie, sticky route and cookie learn.

Below is a brief explanation about how cookie learn method works, which extracted from [Nginx Load Balance](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/):

> The cookie learn method. With this method, NGINX Plus first finds
>   session identifiers by inspecting requests and responses. Then NGINX
>   Plus “learns” which upstream server corresponds to which session
>   identifier. Generally, these identifiers are passed in a HTTP cookie.
>   If a request contains a session identifier already “learned”, NGINX
>   Plus will forward the request to the corresponding server.

My question is that what if two upstream server generated the same session_id, then how does the prxoy server know which upstream server it should send the request?

Comment: hi did you get a answer to your question. I am stuck on the same issue. Only answer I have is that I must use some mechanism like OAuth/JWT.